# Creating Symfony 5 skeleton entity - maker bundle not working

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to run

```
make:entity
```

But I receive an error:

> There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace
>
> You may be looking for a command provided by the "MakerBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev"

I follow that advise and install the bundle by doing:

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

It installs successfully:
[image]

And yet when I try to run `make:entity` I get exactly the same error:

> [image]

> There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace
>
> You may be looking for a command provided by the "MakerBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev"

What am I missing?

Comment: No, the APP_ENV value is prod

Comment: So do I leave off the --dev

Comment: No, that package should not be enabled on production.

Comment: Will do, it seemed like a good thing to do but in retrospect, it is not.

Comment: So, I did switch my server to dev and when I am done with development I will switch it back to production since my client won't give me a dev and prod

Comment: Ok, normally "dev" would be your local development machine. On production these dependencies shouldn't be installed at all (`install --no-dev`). But that's a bit out of scope for this question. You'll get there eventually. Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you `require` a package using the  `--dev` flag, the package will be installed as a development package.

These are packages that should not be enabled on production, when your application is actually deployed. They have to be installed on your development machine, and on your development machine only.

If you check your `bundles.php` file you'll see this line:

```
Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class    => ['dev' => true],
```

This ensures that the bundle is only enabled when your `APP_ENV` variable is set to `dev`.

Since you are running your application on production mode, the bundle is not enabled.

Just change your `APP_ENV` to `dev` so that the package is enabled, and you'll be able to run `make` commands.

Comment: Just a little comment. Check Kernel.php file in your project. Make sure those bundles (from bundles.php) are registered correctly in this file. I don't know why it was done, but some time ago I've seen modified version of this file in one of our projects where specific list of bundles were hardcoded, so it ignores what was in bundles.php